# Not able to find the text using xpath, class or id in webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Not able to find the text using xpath, class or id in webdriver, as it works with Thread.Sleep(5000); method, but its unneccessary to use in all command, any other solution where we can use wait method, as implicit and explicit wait do not provide the proper outcome.

```
String total_count = driver.findElement(By.className("dataTables_info")).getText();
              System.out.println(total_count);
```

Xpath- .//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_info']

Id- DataTables_Table_0_info

```
<div class="fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br">
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_info" class="dataTables_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 21 entries</div>
```

As it giving me the output as below, and if i use wait then also same instead of thread

Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries

Actual-
Showing 1 to 10 of 21

If i used thread.sleep(); then it gives the correct output, but its always need to use in every search or loading the page or waiting for selected button-

Comment: where these numbers are coming? what do you need to wait? please share some more details.

Comment: Hi Akbas, These values are of a table showing data 1 to 10 out of 21 at footer of the table. Its dynamic table, as I am new to the selenium, but in project if values will be same till I update it. Its kind of aria-live relevent.

Comment: what did you do and then get total_count ?

Comment: I need to compare it with database, as total records are correct. And if it is then need pass with query, althogh by extracting the number 21 out of the string. Aftre using the thread it works, but it always need to use. So looking for any other solution or changes.

Answer (score 1):

You might try some waiting (until the right values are "delivered" to your site):

```
WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='DataTables_Table_0_info' and contains(.,'Showing 0')]"));
        return elements.size() == 0;
    }
});

String total_count = driver.findElement(By.className("dataTables_info")).getText();
System.out.println(total_count);
```

Basically you are waiting for the text to NOT say "Showing 0..." anymore.
I will wait for max 5 seconds. You can change this number. If the text changes before these 5 seconds, then it will only wait so far and not the full 5 seconds, which is what you need telling from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Xpath :-

```
//div[@id='DataTables_Table_0_info' and @class='dataTables_info' and contains(.,'Showing 1 to 10 of 21 entries')]
```

If you want to get the String then use below code:-

```
String elem1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='DataTables_Table_0_info' and @class='dataTables_info' and contains(.,'Showing 1 to 10 of 21 entries')]")).getText();
```

Hope it will help you :)